# using nginx to pass subdomains to different apache servers

Tags: apache, nginx, subdomain

I have a 3 servers: 1 nginx and 2 apache webservers

All traffic needs to go through the nginx to the apache servers

```
nginx (192.168.1.100)
web1 (192.168.1.101)
web2 (192.168.1.201)
```

I am having difficulty passing "development" subdomains to the correct servers for clients whose domains are not yet pointed at my nginx server.

I have a root domain for the business "mydomain.com" such that "web1.mydomain.com" should point directly to "web1" and "web2.mydomain.com" should point to "web2"

Further, if I add another sub-domain to the front of web1.mydomain.com or web2.mydomain.com, it should forward the request to the correct server.

example: test.net.web1.mydomain.com should forward to web1 and be served by the vhost on web1 for test.net.

I have tried several server_name configurations but cannot get the subdomains to route correctly.

```
upstream web1 {
    server 192.168.1.101:80;
}

server_name web1.mydomain.com;
proxy_pass http://web1;

server_name *.web1.mydomain.com;
proxy_pass http://$1.web1;

server_name (.*?).web1.mydomain.com;
proxy_pass http://$1.web1;

server_name (.*?).web1.mydomain.com;
proxy_pass http://web1;

server_name .web1.mydomain.com;
proxy_pass http://web1;
```

Neither "web1.mydomain.com" or "test.net.web1.mydomain.com" will forward to the apache server.  I either get a "This site can't be reached" or the default test page for nginx.

Also I have used mxtools and the domain web1.mydomain.com and web2.mydomain.com are pointed at the nginx server ip address.

current .conf file for web1:

```
upstream web1 {
    server 192.168.1.101:80;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .web1.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://web1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current configuration looks correct. What DNS configuration do you have set up for `test.net.web1.mydomain.com`?

Comment: to answer your question: *.web1.mydomain.com is pointed at the nginx ip address as is *.com.web1.mydomain.com.  On a side note, after you responded, I got looking at my shell that I was logged into and turns out I was changing the conf file on the right server, but restarting nginx on a different server.  When I restarted nginx on the correct server, the original configuration worked.  Thank you so much for your time.  Do I leave this question up for others or should I take it down?  Thank you again.